# Sugar CRM 7 enterprise uninstall

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to uninstall sugarCRM 7 and then reinstall.

My config files are set with Xampp php and apache.

I've tried renaming the folder and then running localhost/sugarcrm where sugarcrm is my folder installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to uninstall Sugar then just delete the Sugar directory from your web root.

If you want to reinstall over the top then you can set `'installer_locked' => false` in config.php and then navigate to install.php in your browser.